# Input multiple file names in windows open file dialog box

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 allows you to select multiple files to open at once by using ctrl or shift key. The "File Name" input field at the bottom of the dialog box would auto populate with the following sample:

```
"aaa.txt" "bbb.txt" "ccc.txt" "ddd.txt"
```

I have 14,000 files in a folder and I only need a range of files (approx 500). When I use the shift key to select a range of files, the "File Name" field auto populates all 500 file names. Windows would cut me off at the 260th character when I try to paste in a pre-generated string into the "File Name" field.

Is there a way to bypass the 260 character limit so it would accept my entire string with 500 file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista

"Individual components of a filename (i.e. each subdirectory along the path, and the final filename) are limited to 255 characters, and the total path length is limited to approximately 32,000 characters. However, you should generally try to limit path lengths to below 260 characters (MAX_PATH) when possible. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx for full details."

Unfortunately, it seems that it is hardcoded into the windows file manager to avoid more than 260 characters. If you're doing an operation that could be done by another program (say, moving the files), you could probably avoid this by using another program.